# How to point out a location in google maps?

Tags: html, google-maps, location, point

1. Hi, i am trying to point out the location of my company. It goes to the right location but the pointer is missing. I tried alot of things but it still doesn't work. I am a beginning programmer and i need some help. Thank you for your time.
2. This is my code:

   ```
   <jsp:include page="header.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="subTitle" value="AutoTotaalDiensten - Locatie info" />
   </jsp:include>
    </head>
    <%@ include file="menu.html"%>
   ```

   Locatie

   ```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
     <style>
    #map_canvas {
     height: 400px;
     }
   ```

   ```
   <div id="map_canvas"></div>


         <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

       <script>
             function initialize() {

         var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');

             var map_options = {

                    var mapPin = " http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker.png";
           var Marker = new google.maps.Marker({

                center : new google.maps.LatLng(52.124707, 5.088196),  

                 zoom : 13,


                 mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP


             }

          var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)

      }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
     </script>


     <%@ include file="footer.html"%>
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call Marker.setMap(map) after you initialize the map.

```
 function initialize() {
  var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
  var map_options = {
         center : new google.maps.LatLng(52.124707, 5.088196),  
         zoom : 13,
         mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var mapPin = " http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker.png";
  var Marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position : map_options.center,  
  });
  var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)
  Marker.setMap(map);
} 
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rs4nn/)

Or create it after you create and initailize the map and set its "map" property.

```
 function initialize() {
  var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
  var map_options = {
         center : new google.maps.LatLng(52.124707, 5.088196),  
         zoom : 13,
         mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var mapPin = " http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker.png";
  var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)
  var Marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         map: map,
         position: map.getCenter()
  });
} 
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rs4nn/1/)

Comment: Your parentheses don't match in either example.

Comment: The original example had major problems that I didn't notice (the marker constructor was inside the map_options object, the marker didn't have a position option). Added working fiddles demonstrating the options.